# Cannot access chef-server web interface. (No route to host)

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

I have got chef-server installed on a centos machine. 
Everything is working as expected except that I cannot access the chef-server web interface from another machine on my local network.

I can access the web interface from the centos machine itself:

```
telnet mychefserver.local 4000
Connected
```

If I do the same from my machine I have got:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

I can successfully ping mychefserver.local from my machine

Any idea how to configure nginx with chef-server to access the chef-server from the network?

Answer (score 0):

Since Chef Server 10, the web interface uses normal HTTPS (TCP 443), it only listens on the high ports locally, and nginx proxies as needed to the different backend services. I would try with a normal web browser as telnet isn't exactly great at error messages. Normally I would expect that to mean telnet is getting TCP transmission errors, but maybe it is just confused? If it is really a TCP transmit error then more likely the internal DNS is having issues. `.local` often means mDNS which has uneven support in some places, I would try an actual IP address to be sure.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I used the IP address and nc to test. from my machine I have got that `nc -v 192.168.1.144 4000
nc: connect to 192.168.1.144 port 4000 (tcp) failed: No route to host` and from the server I have got that: `nc -v 192.168.1.144 4000
Connection to 192.168.1.144 4000 port [tcp/terabase] succeeded!`

Comment: From the server using links I got the expected Web interface

Answer (score 0):

My issue was iptables.
I stopped iptables and I can access the chef-server from my local network again.